# HP Compaq laptop hard drive removal

Tags: hard-drive, compaq-laptop

I am having trouble removing the hard drive of my old HP Compaq Laptop, it's model is CQ61-107TU but I can't find it on the HP website. I am more a software person than a hardware person, so I'm not even sure if the thing I think is the hard drive actually is the hard drive. I've added a picture of my computer below.

So basically my computer died and I want to get the hard drive out to see if I can extract the information from it, as I have done previously. However I found a great tutorial for that computer, but this one? Not so much. Please help!

[image: 1]

Comment: You should be able to identify the HDD by its size: a 2.5" HDD is about 96mm long (with another 4mm for a connector) and 69mm wide.

Comment: check out this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWa4m2NvwRc)